# parse error: syntax error expecting catch (T_CATCH)

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I am new to PHP and I'm trying to learn PDO. I'm trying to build a page where I can post information (news and such) to a database and another page where I can view the things in the database.

I've read here that people say you shouldn't use the try catch operator to handle error messages. I understood this as you shouldn't use something like:

**CreateNews.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

// Create presets for connection
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8'";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
    );

// Check if form is being posted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

// Check if fields are empty
if (!$_POST['name'] || !$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['title'] || !$_POST['content'] || !$_POST['timestamp']) {
    echo "<p>Please fill in all of the fields!</p>";
    exit();
}

else {

    try { // Connects to server and executes the transfer of data
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root','', $opt);          
        $sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO news (name, email, title, content, timestamp)
        VALUES (:name, :email, :title, :content, :timestamp)");

        $sth->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);
        $sth->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $sth->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
        $sth->bindParam(':content', $_POST['content']);
        $sth->bindParam(':timestamp', $_POST['timestamp']);

        $sth->execute();

    }

    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo "<p>Data submitted successfully!</p><br />To create another post <a href" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">click here</a>";
}
}

// Close the connection
$pdo = null;
?>
```

So I removed the catch PDOException above and then got the error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting catch (T_CATCH)

If I remove the echo I still get the "expecting catch T_CATCH error.

- Have I misunderstood what people mean when they say that you shouldn't use try catch operators?
- And if so how should I use it?

Please feel free to comment if you notice anything in the code that I've done wrong or unnecessarily. I'm new to all this and still trying to learn! :)

Thanks!

Comment: So you removed the catch, but left the try? You can't have a try without a catch...

Comment: Besides, it's not bad to use try/catch. It's bad form to just use a single catch-all section around your entire script. But that's something entirely different from what you had above.

Comment: Aah of course. Thank you! I totally missed that the try was still there. So it's okay to use a catch independently for certain parts of code?

Comment: `So it's okay to use a catch independently for certain parts of code?` That's really the point of try/catch... you're in control of how you handle exceptions

Comment: A try MUST be followed by a catch. A good practice is to surround with a try the code that may generate an error, and no more.

Comment: I think I understand now. So the catch stops the "big" SQL error from showing and outputs a simpler error message?

Comment: @chipse As the name says it's catching the exception so you have better control over your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I have a feeling I'm gonna have to ask a lot more questions in the future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've read here that people say you shouldn't use the try catch operator to handle error messages.

These people are quite right.

## What to NOT use exceptions for

Exceptions should not be used for normal flow of applications.

Let's take a look at the `inverse($x)` function from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), which returns `1/$x` and throws an exception if you pass in `0` as `$x` since you cannot divide by `0`.

Let's further assume that your variable comes from a posted form, so one could enter `0`. In this case you should check with an `if`-clause for correct values like:

```
<?php
if (intval($_POST['value']) == 0) {
    echo 'You cannot pass 0 into inverse(). Please enter another value.';
} else {
    echo 'We computed the inverse: ' . inverse(intval($_POST['value']));
}
?>
```

You should not use try-catch constructs for this type of use. It is totally expectable in this situation that a user might enter a number the function cannot deal with. You should check inside your normal application flow for wrong values and deal with them.

## What to use exceptions for

Let's assume now that the variable `$x` is filled by `supercomplicated_function`, which always returns a number and never returns `0`. Since you are sure, that the variable will never ever equal `0`, why should you check for this case?

Instead you can use try-catch here:

```
<?php
$x = supercomplicated_function();
try {
    $y = inverse($x);
    echo 'We computed the inverse: ' . $y;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Unexpected situation. Do not know how to go on. Aborting.';
    die();
}
?>
```

## Clues to look for

If you expect some specific error under normal conditions, you should check for them with an `if` statement.
If you do not, let exceptions handle the issue.

In your case, you normally do not expect an exception from a query execution. Possible error causes are `server has gone away` or `deadlock`. This errors are possible, but not under "normal" conditions. So you do not want to check for them with `if` statements (you even cannot check for a possible deadlock beforehand).

Therefore in your case you want to use exceptions. That's totally ok.

Comment: Wow that really clarified how it works! Thank you! :)